# Where is the physical location of user defined .GlobalEnv variables in R and how to delete them permanently?

Tags: r, environment-variables, objectbrowser, revolution-r

**Problem:** 
I needed to use Matlab within R. Then I added relevant package `R.matlab`. 
I defined variables in a demo example of working with Matlab within R.

The defined variables are: data, path, pathname, x, y 
The contents of the variables are:

```
>path
[1] "C:/Revolution/R-Enterprise-7.1/R-3.0.2/library/R.matlab/mat-files"  
>pathname
[1] "C:/Revolution/R-Enterprise-7.1/R-3.0.2/library/R.matlab/mat-files/ABC.mat"  
>data
$A      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1   10   19
....................
 [9,]    9   18   27
$B      [,1]
[1,]    1
..........
[10,]   10

$C
, , 1
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
.......................
, , 3
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   13   15   17
[2,]   14   16   18

attr(,"header")
attr(,"header")$description
[1] "MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: windows, Software: R v2.15.0, Created on: Sat Mar     31 19:50:00 2012"
attr(,"header")$version
[1] "5"
attr(,"header")$endian
[1] "little"
```

**What I needed is:** 
*to obtain a clear R session (no variables/objects in Object Browser) whenever I restart Revolution R.* Currently, whenever I restart Revolution R, the above variables (data, path, pathname, x, y) appear in Object Browser.

**What I did till now:**

1. I completely deleted `R.Matlab` folder from my default library location: 
   C:\Revolution\R-Enterprise-7.1\R-3.0.2\library
2. remove.packages("R.matlab")
3. Closed `Revolution R`; Deleted the existing solution file (.sln) in current R working directory; and restarted `Revolution R`.

Whatever I do, I could not solve: whenever I close `Revolution R` and restart it, the variables (data, path, pathname, x, y) appear in .GlobalEnv in object browser. I want clear .GlobalEnv when I start `Revolution R`.

Comment: There should be an option in the settings that prevent the workspace from being saved.

Comment: Try removing the .Rdata file in the working directory (`getwd()`)? Some of these IDEs save the workspace to disk and load it back the next time you start the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (step by step):

**1.** Delete all objects (In `Revolution R`, from menu: Data - Remove all objects)

**2.** In Revolution R, from menu: tools - options - `Revolution RPE Options` - `Automatically Restore Saved Objects`(selected:False).

**3.** Close `Revolution R`, restart `Revolution R`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the .Rdata file in the working directory (use `getwd()` command if needed)? Some of these IDEs save the workspace to disk and load it back the next time you start them.